# Restyling parent elements the React way

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What would be the "react" way of adding a class to a parent element *when you do not control the parent element*. I am using Material UI and an XGrid which is basically a table. It takes care of rendering rows and columns underneath so I can't modify the `Row` (or wtv) component in anyway. I can only get an event such as onClick or onHover along with an object that contains the plain old HTML element, id, etc.

So when you have a regular HTML Element and no control over the React render function, what is the acceptable way to style it? I feel like I am not allowed to use `classList.toggle('classname')`. I also don't even understand the react way to select elements by id. Is that even allowed?

Comment: Whenever you think about a dynamic thing in React, you need to think about state management.

Comment: My question is really how can I change the state of a component in a library that I don't control? If all they give me is a raw HTMLElement, what am I allowed to do with that? What is the react way? This must be a common issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't style elements in React by selecting them by id, including third-party elements like the ones you're using.

You style them primarily by using **props**. I'll give some examples of different ways to do so with the Material UI library, but if you're not familiar with props, you should read the docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) or watch tutorials.

For ex., the Material UI components have a prop called "classes" that accepts classNames. You can pass classNames as the "classes" prop, and then style the classNames in css.

For ex., in React:

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import react from 'react':

<Button classes="buttonStyles"/>
```

An then in css, style the class as you'd like:

```
.buttonStyles {
   color: red;
}
```

The other way is by styling the **public classes that the third-party library gives you** and triggering these classes by passing in props.

Take a look at the CSS API for Material UI: https://material-ui.com/api/button/#css

`.Mui-disabled`: Pseudo-class applied to the root element if disabled={true}.

This class allows you to style the button if the button is in a disabled state.

TL;DR: Pass in classes as props, or style public classes that are given to you by the library.

Comment: I can't really do any of that. I get one useful event, `onRowHover.` This event gives me one object `GridRowParams`. That object has `element` and not much else that is useful. Thus all I have is a plain `HTMLElement` which is apparently evil so, I don't know what to do. I can't pass props to anything.. I don't have any control over the lower components

Comment: @error_for_now_11 You do have access to the classes available from the CSS API. I linked it above but here it is: https://material-ui.com/api/button/#css. The CSS API is available for all Material UI components and can be used to style the elements.

Comment: Unforunately nowhere can I pass a prop to the row components, I think that is the main issue here. I only render the component that goes inside a cell so, I will just use vanilla.

Comment: @error_for_now_11 Take a look at the link I sent. You don't need props for all of the classes. Ex. `.MuiButton-root` is for the root element, no props needed.